# How can i convert lines with adding n+number

Tags: regex, vim, sed, vi

How can i convert lines  as below using sed or regular expression ?

```
(1,1,'country1'),(2,1,'country2'),(3,1,'country3').....
```

to

```
(1001,1,'country1'),(1002,1,'country2'),(1003,1,'country3')......
```

and

```
(1,1,'city'),(2,2,'city2'),(33,33,'city3').....
```

to

```
(5001,1001,'city1'),(5002,1002,'city2'),(5033,1033,'city3')......
```

> I want 1000 + n so it should be 1000 + 1 = 1001 or 1000 + 25 = 1025
>   instead of 100025

Comment: What determines whether `1` becomes `1001` or `5001`?

Comment: did u try it before posting ?.try to post the code which you had wrote..

Comment: no mater i need to add with any default number that i used there 5000+n and 1000+n

Comment: you want `"1000" + n` or `1000+n`? e.g if `n=100`, you want to have `1100` or `1000100`?

Comment: also why for `country`, the 2nd number in `(..)` were not changed, but they were in `city` example?

Comment: i want 1000 + n 
so it should be 1000 + 1 = 1001 or 1000 + 25 = 1025 instead of 100025

Comment: @Egemen then forget the regex, also the `sed` is wrong tool to do it.

Comment: @Kent, so what should i use for it ?

Comment: @Egemen i already asked you about this issue?

Comment: vim can do it, but requirement must be clear.

Comment: @AvinashRaj when did you ask? I cannot see in comment

Comment: @Kent. Logic is clear that i just want to grep any number and addition with a number given statically such as 5000 + n .

Comment: @Egemen then why for country only first was changed, but for city, both were changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### vim solution

For the first case: only the first number will be incremented by 1000:

```
:%s/(\zs\d\+/\=submatch(0)+1000/g
```

For the 2nd example: two numbers must be changed, first number +5k, and 2nd number + 1k:

```
:%s/\v\(\zs(\d+),(\d+)/\=string(submatch(1)+5000).','.string(submatch(2)+1000)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty convoluted perl one-liner

```
perl -F'[(]' -ane '
    BEGIN {@add=(shift,shift)}
    print join "(", map {
        @t = split /,/,$_,-1;
        for $i (0,1) {$t[$i] += $add[$i] if $t[$i]}
        join ",", @t
    } @F
' 5000 1000 <<END
(1,1,'city'),(22,22,'city2'),(333,333,'city3')
END
```

```
(5001,1001,'city'),(5022,1022,'city2'),(5333,1333,'city3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Through Perl,

```
$ echo "(1,1,'country1'),(2,1,'country2'),(3,1,'country3')....." | perl -pe 's/\(\K(\d+)/1000+$1/eg'
(1001,1,'country1'),(1002,1,'country2'),(1003,1,'country3').....
$ echo "(1,1,'city'),(2,2,'city2'),(33,33,'city3')....." | perl -pe 's/\(\K(\d+)/5000+$1/eg;s/,\K(\d+)/1000+$1/eg'
(5001,1001,'city'),(5002,1002,'city2'),(5033,1033,'city3').....
```

`\K` discards the previously matched characters and `e` modifier helps to do some arithmetic operations on the replacement part.

Consider this example.

```
's/\(\K(\d+)/1000+$1/eg'
```

- `\(` Matches the literal `(` symbol.
- `\K` discards the previously matched `(` character from consideration. It's just like a positive lookebhind. `\(\K` would be written as `(?<=\()`. Next `(\d+)` captures the following one or more digits. Now this number is stored inside the group index 1.
- So `(` plus the following number is matched and replaced by the output of this `1000+$1` arithmetic operation. Note that `$1` refers to the number located inside the group index1. If the number stored is `1` than `1000+1` yields `1001` and this is the replacement string.
- `g` modifier helps to do a global match.
- `e` modifier allows arithmetic functions on the replacement part.

Comment: thats also works thanks!  but vim would be much easier for me that i understand more clearly.

Comment: Thats your choice. I added some explanation. I think this would help you in future...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bit very hackish (mind you, all approaches with awk or sed that try to get around building a proper parser are going to be), but if your file format is as strict as you make it look, then

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "("; ORS=""; FS = ","; OFS = FS } NF == 0 { next } { $1 += 5000; if(index($3, "country") == 2) $2 += 1000; print RS $0 }' filename
```

should work. That is

```
BEGIN { 
  RS  = "("                        # record separator
  ORS = ""                         # output record separator
  FS  = ","                        # field separator
  OFS = FS                         # output field separator
}
NF == 0 { next }                   # lines without fields skipped (that is the
                                   # virtual record before the first openparen)
{                                  # then for each line:
  $1 += 5000                       # First field increased by 5000
  if(index($3, "country") == 2) {  # Second field increased by 1000 if it
    $2 += 1000                     # describes a country
  }
  print RS $0                      # print the whole shebang
}
```

This requires a little explanation.

Since `RS` is `(`, the records are `1,1,'country1'),`, `2,1,'country2'),` and so forth (including, importantly, the `),` at the end.

Since `FS` is `,`, fields are, in the example of the first record, `1`, `1`, `'country1')` and an empty token.

Since `ORS` is empty, awk will not put a record separator between the records upon output.

Since `OFS` is the same as `FS`, fields will be separated in the output the same way they were in the input .

Then:

```
  print RS $0
```

prints all fields separated by commas (`OFS` = `FS` = `","`), prepended by an openparen (which is what `RS` is), followed by the output record separator -- which is empty. So the formatting remains the same as in the input, and only the fields we changed are actually changed.